# Instantiating javascript class in Node.js

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Why is the following code gives me an error?

```
// In Foo.js
class Foo {
    constructor(a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
}

module.exports = Foo

// In Index.js
var foo = new require('path/Foo.js')('param');
```

This gives me **Class constructor Foo cannot be invoked without 'new'**.

Thanks.

Comment: Because the code shown is invoking the `require` function with `new` rather than your constructor?

Comment: @nnnnnn I forgot to do module.exports at the end. If i do this, require('path/Foo.js) returns Foo class isn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that in your code the `new` operator is applied to the `require()` function, not to what `require()` returns. That is, this:

```
var foo = new require('path/Foo.js')('param');
```

...is like doing this:

```
var foo = ( new require('path/Foo.js') )('param');
```

...or:

```
var temp = new require('path/Foo.js');
var foo = temp('param');
```

Try the following instead, so that `new` is applied to your class:

```
var Foo = require('path/Foo.js');
var foo = new Foo('param');
```

Comment: Thank you! I thought "require("path/Foo.js")" is same as "Foo".